# How ethical is to ask for a voluntary excedence as soon as I have my contract renewed?

Tags: ethics, leave, spain

First of all, I don't know exactly the term in English for an "excedence", it's the right to leave the job for X time, but granting a place in the company after that X time. I think it's to [leave on personal grounds](https://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/traduccion/excedencia+voluntaria.html).
In my country (Spain) as far as I know from what I've searched, the only requisite is to have a year seniority.
For me, that full year will be in the 1st of July, when they would renew me (I've been talking with my boss and he told me that he wanted to do it).

The thing is that I'm thinking of returning to study a Higher Level Education Cycle, which would take me another year, and as I would start studying on September I would like to tell him with some anticipation my intentions. Also I would like to return to this job, as I've been comfortable with it and my coworkers.

An small chronogram of the dates

- 1st July 2021, starts my renewed contract
- Same 1st July, I reach the minimum time to ask for an "excedence", at this time (some days/weeks later) I would ask for it
- Approx 1st September, I would start to study
- Approx July 2022 I would return to my job

My question is, how ethical is to as soon as I've started my new period of work, to ask for that "excedence", probably making a mess in my boss's plans?

Comment: This sounds like a [sabbatical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sabbatical), or [leave of absence](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leave_of_absence)

Comment: HorusKol for what I've searched I think that [Leave on personal grounds](https://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/traduccion/excedencia+voluntaria.html) suits better, but I wasn't sure enough to put it on the post.

Comment: Deagle, I disagree. I would say that leave on personal grounds gives people the impression that you have some sort of problem. Maybe your child is sick, or you have a mental health problem, or you just want to write poetry for a year. Sabbatical is more neutral.

Answer (score 3):

Be honest about it. If you communicate clearly that you like your job and the team chances are you can come to an agreement that lets you rejoin the company (or even better: still work for the company during your study time. That's how it's done in Germany).

If you don't say anything until end of June, your boss might not take it very well.

Comment: I don't think about working for the company during my studies, because both would be at the same time, in the morning, and I don't know if I would be able to do both without leaving one of them (if they were at different hours)

Comment: Agreed.  If your goal is to be working at your current workplace long-term, then you want to discuss it with them sooner rather than later, and see what you can work out so that everyone involved is taken care of.

Comment: It would also strengthen the OP's case if he could show a benefit to the company from doing this study

Answer (score 0):

> Be honest about it. [...]
> If you don't say anything until end of June, your boss might not take it very well.

Don't do that. Wait until your contract is renewed before you say anything. Two months of advanced notice for an unpaid sabbatical is plenty of time. Not only that, but according to you, that kind of notice doesn't seem to contradict your existing contract. Do what the contract says.

That sabbatical is something you've earned. Take advantage of it. If you tell them what you're planning to do before your contract is renewed, your contract is not going to be renewed. Your boss may have no say on the matter.

Even if you really like your boss and even if he really likes you. He doesn't make up the rules. Someone in HR may just tell him to let you go instead. And then you'll just be unemployed for two months before you start your studies, and you won't have a guaranteed job to go back to after your studies are done.